# Template inside template not working in alpine js

Tags: alpine.js

I am facing a strange issue in Alpine js. So, I receive a multidimensional array from the backend and have to present that array in table format. But, alpine js won't allow me to do so. Here is how my code looks like

```
<tbody>
<template x-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
    <template x-for="(shopping_item, subIndex) in user.shopping_items" :key="subIndex">
        <tr>
            <td x-text="shopping_item.item_name" class="text-right"></td>
            <td x-text="shopping_item.quantity" class="text-right"></td>
            <td x-text="shopping_item.total_price.toFixed(2)" class="text-right"></td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</template>
</tbody>
```

the loop only run once, then give an error saying `shopping_item` is not defined but when i add a `<div>` between these two templates like this.

```
<template x-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
    <div>
        <template x-for="(shopping_item, subIndex) in user.shopping_items" :key="subIndex">
            <tr>
                <td x-text="shopping_item.item_name" class="text-right"></td>
                <td x-text="shopping_item.quantity" class="text-right"></td>
                <td x-text="shopping_item.total_price.toFixed(2)" class="text-right"></td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

then, it works fine without any errors but messes up the table design. Is there any better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share an example data for `user`? Maybe you can solve this using only one loop.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for):

> `x-for` MUST be declared on a `<template>` element That `<template>` element MUST contain only one root element

This single root cannot be a `<template>` tag.

P.S. If it ruins your styling, you might need a different approach, e.g. different HTML structure, or different way of handling your data.

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes#autocorrection)

> An interesting “special case” is tables. By DOM specification they must have tbody tag, but HTML text may omit it. Then the browser creates tbody in the DOM automatically....You see? The tbody appeared out of nowhere. We should keep this in mind while working with tables to avoid surprises.

Perhaps adding a tbody instead of a div could fix the styling issue.